# How to handle deserializing JSON data that varies?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, poco

**Question Background:**

I am calling the Amazon Product Advertising API and receiving from their service a list of products in a JSON format.

**The Issue:**

Sadly the JSON response varies depending on the parameters supplied to the API. For example: searching for 'Sporting Goods' gives a slightly different response to 'Watches'.

The following gives a very simple example of the differences:

Sporting Goods JSON as received from the API:

```
{
    "Item": {
        "ID": "145",
        "Title": "Football",
        "ImageUrl": "http://amazon.com/football.jpg",
        "Shipping": "UK",
        "ListPrice": "7.99"
    }
}
```

Watches JSON as received from the API:

```
{
    "Item": {
        "ID": "567",
        "Title": "RolexWatch",
        "ImageUrl": "http://amazon.com/RolexWatch.jpg",
        "Shipping": "UK",
        "ListPrice": "£7000.00",
        "SalePrice": "£6500.00"   <------------- extra item in Watches JSON
    }
}
```

I am currently using NewtonSoft To deserialize the two responses into two distinct C# models i.e:

```
 public class SportingGoods
    {
      public string ID {set;get;}
      public string Title {set;get;}
      public string ImagesUrl {set;get;}
      public string Shipping{set;get;}
      public string ListPrice{set;get;}
    }

public class Watches
    {
      public string ID {set;get;}
      public string Title {set;get;}
      public string ImagesUrl {set;get;}
      public string Shipping{set;get;}
      public string ListPrice{set;get;}
      public string SalePrice{set;get;}
    }
```

I am finding there are other variations in the JSON response from the Amazon  API. **How can I handle this desearlization properly when the JSON data varies so much? I cant keep creating different models when I'm not 100% sure what the JSON will look like.**

Answer (score 4):

You can use a dynamic type in C# using `JObject.Parse()`  You'll just have to be careful using it as fields may or may not be present.

```
dynamic foo = JObject.Parse(jsonText);
string bar = foo.Bar; // bar = "something"
```

Answer (score 1):

In the example you gave, it looks like the only difference between the two models is that one has `SalePrice` field while the other does not.  Otherwise, they are identical.  This scenario is actually pretty common and is not a big deal to handle.

By default, JSON.Net will skip over class members for which there is no corresponding field in the JSON, or vice versa.  So you could simply define a single `Product` model that has all of the possible product fields you're interested in and use it for both of these cases.  In the case of sporting goods, the `SalePrice` will simply be null.  If there's an extra field that turns up in the JSON later that you don't really care about, no problem--it will be ignored.

```
public class Product
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ImagesUrl { get; set; }
    public string Shipping { get; set; }
    public string ListPrice { get; set; }
    public string SalePrice { get; set; }
}
```

Now, if your JSON varies more wildly, for example if a field is sometimes a string and sometimes a list of strings, then you have to start looking at other approaches.  One possibility is writing a custom [`JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) to handle the differences.  Another possibility is deserializing into a [`JObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm) or `dynamic` instead of using strongly-typed classes.